# LuaLaTeX and Gnuplot (Cairolatex terminal): "Undefined control sequence. \inputencoding"

Tags: luatex, input-encodings, gnuplot, epslatex

I recently went from pdflatex to lualatex. Quite happy so far except of one thing: I am unable to include Gnuplot graphs created using the cairolatex terminal (options "pdf input"). The error I get is "Undefined control sequence. \inputencoding". The problematic part in all the tex files created by cairolatex is this:

```
% Encoding inside the plot.  In the header of your document, this encoding
% should to defined, e.g., by using
% \usepackage[cp1252,<other encodings>]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{cp1252}%
```

Of course I do not use the inputenc package anymore since it is obsolete for LuaLaTeX. I also tried using the epslatex terminal, results are the same. Any idea what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you could add a dummy definition for \inputencoding to avoid the error but if the file is really cp1257 and contains some non-ascii you will run into problems, you should try to get utf8 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Put "set encoding utf8" into the gnuplot script.